# Jquery or PHP - show link based on checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a Document Request form which asks for some simple details and a few checkboxes where a user requests the document they are interested in.

Name
Email
Documents Requested
 - Document 1
 - Document 2
 - Document 3
 - Submit

When they hit Submit, I take them to a thankyou page and my client is emailed the results so she knows what docs were requested.

Now the dumb part is that we take users to a 'thankyou' page that has ALL documents ready for download regardless of which ones they are interested in. Ideally I'd like to only give them the requested PDFs.

I suspect I can do this by either of the two methods below but was wondering what was the 'best'

1. I use a PHP script to email the files based on the checkboxes requested
2. I use some Jquery toggle script to toggle a DIV based on the checkboxes requested.

Obviously, I am not proficient in either approach but can modify existing examples to get to work. Would anyone have such an example?

Many thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

It is better to manipulate the output of "Thank You" page on PHP level. Just make conditions based on form checkboxes.

```
if($_POST['checkbox1'])
{
  // display document #1
}
if($_POST['checkbox2'])
{
  // display document #2
}
if($_POST['checkbox1'])
{
  // display document #2
}
```